# ECS Fargate fails randomly without logs, with container ExitCode 139

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to deploy ETL pipeline on AWS,
Pipeline architecture consist of step function to manage the whole pipeline, it consists of 10 parallel (independent) Fargate (pipeline) invoked using map in step function and a Lambda (Error Notifier),

I have used python 3.7 as base image to build my docker image, pipeline is successfully deployed, but it sometimes randomly fails with container exit code 139.

After further research, I found out that it is sigsegv error (same as error code 11 of linux kernel), related invalid memory access

I am not sure how to rectify this error

Comment: What's running inside your containers?

Comment: I am running a ETL application in python:



requirement file:
google-cloud-bigquery==2.6.2
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.0.0
Google-cloud-pubsub==2.6.1
google-cloud-storage==1.35.0
google-oauth2-tool==0.0.3
google-cloud-logging==2.5.0
traceback2==1.4.0
openpyxl==3.0.6
numpy==1.19.4
pandas==1.2.0
fastparquet==0.5.0
pyarrow==2.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
requests==2.25.1
bigquery_schema_generator==1.4
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.6.0
boto3==1.18.7

Comment: @Hcaertnit 
this service would fetch data from s3, process it, store it to gcs and ingest it to BQ
using lambda is creating bottle neck in pipeline, because of time limit imposed on it. To rectify that we are deploying pipeline in fargate

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[UPDATE]

Recently found out that problem was, image was built x86_84 mac machine, and was deployed on x86_84 ubuntu system, because of that we got SIGTERM error (error code:7 for linux, and error code: 139 for docker), just redeployed the images AWS codebuild, and everything worked perfectly fine from then on.

Comment: Which dependencies?

Comment: removed pandas library

Comment: Thanks. What is is about that library that made it incompatible with ECS fargate? Do you know?

Comment: Recently found out that problem was, image was built intel mac machine, and was deployed on x86_84 ubuntu system, because we got SIGTERM error (error code:7 for linux, and error code: 139 for docker), just redeployed the images AWS codebuild, and everything worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have recently upgraded from the .net 3.1 to .net 6 docker images and this has stopped any docker containers exiting for no reason.

Comment: Hi @luke you found out what's is causing the crash in your containers in ecs running .net core application?

Comment: @DiegoDias I ended up just making sure I was on a more up to date version of the .net runtime image and this stopped the problem all together. The problem forced me to have to move from an older version of .net to a newer one, essentially. I'm using `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` and it's fine, but even that's probably getting old now.

Comment: @Luke we found the cause of the problem. In our case, the IronPdf paid package was the reason for crashing and killing our tasks in ECS without leaving tracks in logs.